# Is there a Persian Calendar for Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, calendar

Is there a **Persian Calendar** available for **Ubuntu 16.04** ?

Comment: This may be helpful: https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/natty/jalali-calendar/

Comment: I could see for _[gnome desktop](https://github.com/Gahshomar/gahshomar)_ didn't see for unity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/Gahshomar/gahshomar) is a good one.

You need to install [flatpak](http://flatpak.org/) which takes a while.Do as follow:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:alexlarsson/flatpak
sudo apt update
sudo apt install flatpak

flatpak remote-add --from gnome https://sdk.gnome.org/gnome.flatpakrepo
flatpak remote-add --from gnome-apps https://sdk.gnome.org/gnome-apps.flatpakrepo
```

Then download the latest release (.flatpak file) from [here](https://github.com/Gahshomar/gahshomar/releases).
Currently latest version is `4.4.1` so you need to download [this](https://github.com/Gahshomar/gahshomar/releases/download/v4.4.1/gahshomar-4.4.1.flatpak) file.

Then according to [wiki](https://github.com/Gahshomar/gahshomar/wiki/Installation) page open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> and go to where the `.flatpak` file is downloaded. For example if it is in `Downloads` folder you should type:

```
cd ~/Downloads
```

Now install the file:

```
flatpak install -y gahshomar-4.4.1.flatpak
```

Run it (you may need a logout/login before running it):

```
flatpak run gahshomar
```

and finally activate its plugins as pictures show:

[image]

[image]

* Maybe write a bash file for the whole process and share it later...

Comment: Thanks for your advise , i got following error after the final step :) *Invalid id gahshomar: Names must contain at least 2 periods*

Comment: @SaeedTabrizi: Just search "gahshomar" in dash (first icon on the left top, where you can search installed applications) instead of that step and run by clicking on it's icon.

Answer (score 6):

Jalali calendar is a small and portable free software library to manipulate date and time in Jalali calendar system. Installation:

```
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install jcal
```

Source:

http://www.nongnu.org/jcal/

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a Persian calendar for Ubuntu 22.04 and the [Persian Calendar](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/240/persian-calendar/) GNOME extension ([GitHub repo](https://github.com/omid/Persian-Calendar-for-Gnome-Shell)) is what I've chosen.

If you don't have Extension Manager installed on your computer, you can install it by entering the command in the Terminal

```
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-manager
```

Open it and click the Browse tab to search for extensions.

Comment: @muru Thanks for the edit.